# Query Performance Optimization in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Query Profile View,which of these are to be **specifically** considered to increase query performance altogether ?

A.Byte scanned

B.Partition scanned out of total partition

C.% scanned from cache

D.Byte passed over network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all contribute. Scanning more bytes will take longer and if you have a slow network, retrieving the results will take longer

However, partition pruning has a very noticeable impact. The more partitions you can eliminate and the more you can scan from cache, the faster the query